# How do I solve a var.map is not a function TypeError?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, typeerror, strapi

I'm working on a blog page for my website that's based on Next.js, written on TypeScript and that uses Strapi as CMS API.

The following code snippet is giving me a **Server Error** that says `TypeError: posts.map is not a function` which I have no idea why.

```
type BlogPageProps = {
  posts: PostData[];
};

const BlogPage = ({ posts }: BlogPageProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({ duration: 700 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <SEO title={`Blog | ${SITE_NAME}`} />

      <AnimationContainer animation="appearFromAbove">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <PostCard effect="fade-up" key={post.id} post={post} />
        ))}
      </AnimationContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogPage;
```

The PostData[] is only a type that consists of the following parameters :

```
export type PostData = {
  id: PostID;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  slug: string;
  author: PostAuthor;
  category: PostCategory;
  created_by: PostCreatedBy;
  updated_by: PostCreatedBy;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  cover: PostCover;
};
```

I'm thinking this has something to do with the code from the API instance itself or perhaps some dependency issue? I'd appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: wherever you do `<BlogPage posts={thisIsNotAnArray} />`, check the object you pass to this component.

Comment: If `BlogPage ` is a page component, where is the data fetching method for that page? How/where are you fetching the data for `posts`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all Console the posts and check is it undefined, null, or  a type of posts must be array

I think you should try following

posts.posts.map()

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but where should I put the "console.log(posts)"? I don't think the sintax is the issue here because I did what you've said and it didn't work

Comment: Try above the return statement in your source.

Comment: It doesn't work because the page doesn't load properly with the error

Comment: ok, console wherever you have called BlogPage component and also make sure alias var must be posts={some_array}